# How can I solve strftime TypeError when making a POST request in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API that contains a DateTimeField using Django but I am getting the following error "TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object"  I have tried checking different sources but I haven't found a solution.

- The error is arising from the start_date line.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def question_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse("Вопрос не создан")
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        poll_question = request.POST['poll_question']
        title = request.POST['title']
        start_date = datetime.strftime(request.POST['start_date'],'%Y-%m-%d')
        Question.objects.create(poll_question=poll_question,title=title, start_date=start_date)
        return HttpResponse("Вопрос создан")
    else:
        return "Попробуйте снова"
```

Comment: if you want convert a str in a datetime, you need to use strptime() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an easy way to fix this is to convert the object to a string according to a given format using `datetime.strptime` as stated in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Your view will now be written as:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def question_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse("Вопрос не создан")
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        poll_question = request.POST['poll_question']
        title = request.POST['title']
        start_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST['start_date'],'%Y-%m-%d')
        Question.objects.create(poll_question=poll_question,title=title, start_date=start_date)
        return HttpResponse("Вопрос создан")
    else:
        return "Попробуйте снова"
```

> `strptime` Parse a string into a datetime object given a corresponding format.
> (As per the datetime documentation)

Answer (score 0):

There is two methods in datetime:

- **strftime**: used to convert date object into string.
- **strptime**: used to convert string into date object.

In your case, you need a second one. The code of yours will be:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST['start_date'],'%Y-%m-%d')
```